# SQL Derive multiple columns from one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have 1 table called Location, containing columns LocationID, ParentLocationID and LocationName. I want to display a table with "Location" and "Parent Location" both derived from the LocationID. How might I do this ?

Example:

Say for example my table looked like this:

LocationID | ParentLocationID | LocationName

```
1      |       3          |     abc

2      |       3          |     def

3      |      NULL        |     xyz
```

I want my returned table to look like:

LocationName | ParentLocationName

```
 abc         |       xyz
 def         |       xyz
```

Comment: Some sample data and the desired result would help

Comment: @SafetyFish dont post data in comment. edit your question with the data and reply with a comment saying you add more info. and use `@userName` so he get a notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a self join. For example:

```
SELECT a.LocationID, a.LocationName,
       parent.LocationID, parent.LocationName
FROM Location a
INNER JOIN Location parent ON a.ParentLocationID=parent.LocationID;
```

Comment: btw you probably should go with `LEFT JOIN` because Im sure some Location doesnt have parent. Unless you have a recursive wormhole.

Comment: It depends on the OP's requirements. With an `INNER JOIN`, only Locations with parents will show up. Perhaps that is what is wanted.